# Datepicker onload trigger?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does the datepicker have an equivalent to onFirstLoad the way it has an onSelect function or something similar?  If not, is it possible to simulate such a trigger for datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the datepicker div is now present like so:

```
$(function() {
   if ($('#ui-datepicker-div').length) {
      // Datepicker is present
      console.log("Now loaded");
   }
});
```

*Note: If what you want to do is datepicker specific, then I would recommend looking at the datepicker options to specify what you want.*

Also, if you are waiting for JQuery UI to be loaded, look at [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Snippet below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>

<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<div id="dlog">Not loaded</div>
 
<script>
    $(function() {
      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div').length) {
           $('#dlog').text("Datepicker now loaded");
      }
    });
</script>
 
</body>
```